# Django Admin Login Background

Tags: django, django-admin, django-templates

how can i change only background image of admin login site in django? i have tried some method but didnt achieved.

i have put base_site.html to under templates\admin.

what is next for coding about background image?

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}{{ title }} | {% trans 'Django site admin' %}{% endblock %}


{% block extrastyle %}
<style type="text/css">
# body {background-color: #444444;}
</style>
{% endblock %}


{% block branding %}
<h1 id="site-name">{% trans 'Admin Login' %}</h1>
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Is the background-color attribute you've added working? If so you can use `body {background-image:url('image.png');}` to set an image. Or is your problem that the code you provided isn't setting the background-color?

Comment: background-color is also not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct code is:

```
{% block extrastyle %}
<style type="text/css">
body.login {background-color: #444444;}
</style>
{% endblock %}
```

The problem was the `#` in the css which refers to an id, ie `<some_tag id="body">` rather than `<body>`. `body.login` targets a body tag with a `login` class, ie `<body class="login">`, which is what the django admin site uses to identify the body of just the login screen.

Comment: The problem was the `#` which refers to an id, ie `<some_tag id="body">` rather than `<body>`. `body.login` targets a body tag with a `login` class, ie `<body class="login">`, which is what the django admin site uses to identify the body of just the login screen.